# Adding WFS service to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wfs, data-interoperability

I was under the impression that the Data Interop extension was needed to use a WFS service in ArcGIS Desktop, as outlined [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-a-wfs-service-to-arcmap.htm). The page specifically mentions that a DI license is required.

Now I found [another page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/adding-a-wfs-connection.htm) that shows something different:

[image: screenshot of the Catalog Window]

There is no mention of DI, and apparently there is a new option under *GIS Servers* ('Add WFS Server').

I don't have this option, in ArcGIS 10.3.1 or 10.4.1, so how do I get it? I thought I needed to install DI after all, so I did that, but the option is still not there, nor can I find a way to add it manually. Is this part of the [Production Mapping](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/production-mapping) extension?

I have an ArcGIS Enterprise license.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-a-wfs-service-to-arcmap.htm) guide you will be able to add a WFS under Interoperability Connections not under GIS Servers.
[image]

At first I did not have this option either, then I realized that I did not install the interoperability extension, I merely added the license. So make sure you both have a license and install the extension.

Comment: That does not answer my question: How do I get the Add WFS Server options, as displayed in the screenshot?

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to add a WFS in general. As to your question: I actually remember that it was there in previous versions, but I don't have it now either. I can only guess that they removed it in the newer versions.